# Затенение элементов в ExtJS с выводом сообщения 'Loading...'

Tags: javascript, extjs

Как в **ExtJS** затенить элементы, желательно с выводом сообщения '*Loading...*' ?
Например нужно затенить окно или панель пока грузятся данные.

Comment: Какая версия ExtJs?

Comment: Последняя на данный момент - 4.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
var domElement = Ext.get( "elemId" );
domElement.mask( "Загрузка...", "yourCssCls" );
```

**UPD1:**

Или вот так:
http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.LoadMask